# Need to modify boot options, Windows not working (dual booting ubuntu and windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I have just installed Ubuntu.  It has been a long painful road as I've made every mistake possible.  Finally things are looking up.  When I turn on the computer I get to a boot menu.  Ubuntu works, but windows does not.

If I try to select windows it goes to a black screen, then back to the boot menu.

I believe the issue is that the boot menu is trying to open up windows from `dev/sda1` but in reality windows is in `dev/sda2`.  This results in a black screen happening for about five seconds and then it takes me back to the boot menu!  Please help!  I'd love to keep Ubuntu, but I need to access Windows.

Here is the complete boot info log I got:

============================ Boot Info Summary: ===============================

=> Lilo is installed in the MBR of `/dev/sda`.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda1 
                   and looks at sector 781374472 of the same hard drive 
                   for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                   for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive. No errors found 
                   in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  
Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD
```

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ntfs
Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
Operating System:  Windows 7
Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe
```

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       Extended Partition
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       ext4
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info: 
Operating System:  Ubuntu 11.10
Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /boot/grub/core.img
```

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

```
File system:       swap
Boot sector type:  -
Boot sector info:
```

============================= Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   695,974,276   695,767,429   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         695,975,934   976,771,071   280,795,138   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         695,975,936   968,652,799   272,676,864  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         968,654,848   976,771,071     8,116,224  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

```
Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        907251C67251B1A8                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        60EC5404EC53D2C0                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        cb187c79-003c-4187-a465-a65086a232e0   ext4       
/dev/sda6        34f6876e-7e0e-4c27-aef7-54250c4fdea7   swap
```

================================ Mount points: ================================

```
Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda5        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
```

========================== `sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg`: ===========================

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently run into an issue with GRUB as well. Here is my post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem/119661#119661.

Boot into Ubuntu. Download and run [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) to fix your issue. Choose "Recommended Repair (repairs most frequent problems)" option.

Actually, it looks like you have Lilo, so this solution may not work for you. As an option, you could replace Lilo with GRUB, as GRUB is the most popular boot loader.